# Cannot manipulate string text obtained by Interop Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I fetched the headings using this code

```
foreach (Paragraph paragraph in this.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs)
{
    Style style = paragraph.get_Style() as Style;
    string styleName = style.NameLocal;
    string text = paragraph.Range.Text;
    if( styleName == "Heading 1" )
    { 
        myList.Add(text);
    } 
}
```

as the list is string and also the text fetched is also string so I should be able to perform all string operation but I cannot perform like join, concat or any other operations. Basically it seems as a string but doesn't function as a string.

Comment: When you use the debugger to step through the code.. what is the value of `styleName` what is the value of `text` can you provide a little bit more information..

Comment: text="Function R1\r"
styleName="Heading 1"

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by Replace("\r","").
When paragraph.range.text is used to read text it add \r(replace) at the end of the text. Simply remove it by  Paragraph.Range.Text.Replace("\r","") when storing in a string.

Thank you MethodMan for guiding me to the solution.